# modular arithmetic problem puzzle

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If you have:

$N\equiv 2\mod 3 ,\: N\equiv 3 \mod 4 , \: N\equiv 4 \mod 5 $

What is N?

Comment: Maybe you can look into this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: It helps to note that $N+1$ is divisible by $3,4,5$.

Comment: I'm for $N=433877219$.

Comment: @lulu you re the guy I am looking for :D

Comment: Perhaps $N=60a-1$?